# Override view.phtml of layered navigation not working

Tags: magento-1.8

I am trying to override `magentoe\app\design\frontend\rwd\mytheme\template\instockonly\catalog\layer\view.phtml` file in my custom module say instockonly -

module config.xml file -

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Namespace_InStockOnly>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </Namespace_InStockOnly>
        </modules>
    <frontend>
            <routers>
                <instockonly>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Namespace_InStockOnly</module>
                        <frontName>instockonly</frontName>
                    </args>
                </instockonly>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <instockonly>
                        <file>instockonly.xml</file>
                    </instockonly>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

Here is module xml file

```
//path magentoe\app\design\frontend\rwd\enterprise\layout\instockonly.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
        <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>instockonly/catalog/layer/view.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>    
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

and path of phtml file is -

```
magentoe\app\design\frontend\rwd\enterprise\template\instockonly\catalog\layer\view.phtml
```

where i am doing wrong,because i have tried a lot but still i am unable to overirde phtml file.
Please suggest ASAP.